# Should I use Sequential Promises or Promise.all

Tags: javascript

I have a few functions that I need use when submitting a form:

1. a function that uploads a file to S3 -  `childRef.current.upload()`
2. a function that posts the form data to Google Sheets - `submitHandler()`
3. a function that submits the form data to a lambda function that creates a pdf of the data and submits to S3 -  `formPdf()`

However I get a situation where sometimes the upload function will fail but the other functions will succeed (or other permutations) leaving only a partial completion of the form submit.

This is the code I am using:

```
async function onSubmit() {
                if (selectedFiles) {
                        const sleep = function (ms) {
                                return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
                        }
                        await Promise.all([sleep(1000), childRef.current.upload(), submitHandler(), formPdf()])

                        onOpen()
                } else {
                        setFilesAttached(1)
                        console.log(filesAttached)
                }
        }
```

Should I run these promises sequentially with the upload first? If so what is the best way of doing this?

Many thanks

Nick

Comment: _"Should I run these promises sequentially"_ - yes unless you can easily rollback the others in case one fails. _"what is the best way of doing this"_ - not using `Promise.all`, but awaiting each of them, and wrapping all of this with a `try/catch` in case of a failure. Also, out of curiosity, why are you using the `sleep` function? In your example, it just ensures that the `Promise.all` will take at least 1 second before resolving, even if everything else is faster. Is there a reason?

Comment: Depending on the general reason for something failing, you might consider just retrying any failed requests